import extended properties of sql server database from xls file
I have a list of extended properties for all databases in an excel file. How can I import that into extended properties of each database in sql server.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The TSQL script way of adding an Extended property is via sp_addextendedproperty
Slightly altered example from the documentation:
USE AdventureWorks2022;
GO

EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = 'Postal code is a required column.',
    @level0type = 'SCHEMA', @level0name = N'Person',
    @level1type = 'TABLE', @level1name = N'Address',
    @level2type = 'COLUMN', @level2name = N'PostalCode';
GO

While you could create the statement in Excel through string concatenation that would be mainly useful for a single database only.
If you have multiple databases you might be better off using some programming language outside of SQL like PowerShell (perhaps with dbatools module) and looping through the rows while passing the values to the proc above.

Probably the ImportExcel module helps OP here too

Thanks. How can I import information into the extended properties of each database from xlsx file by query. I have 7 property for each database that I wanna enter to extended properties.
